# Java: Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (2)

Tags: java

I am new in Java & creating a student Management program, i have go an below error
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError***

but the thing is i also tried to compile & run simple Helloworld.java program, it shows the same error

i refer many of the solutions in stack overflow which belongs to this question but 
javac -cp.HelloWorld.java
or
java -classpath.HelloWorld.java

also not workes..

Please help me & guide me why is it so..I think in the code i did not made any mistake.

Comment: How do you compile and run your program?

Comment: oh yes it works...!
I have just remove .java from the end, working command is

**java HelloWorld**

Comment: That period `.` right after the `-cp` and `-classpath` doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 2):

The classpath is the path to the Java class files, not to the Java source files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be that you're trying to run the java executable on the java file itself.

When you run `javac` it emits a bytecode compiled version of your java class for the java executable to run. The bytecode version of your **HelloWorld.java** class should look like **HelloWorld.class**.  Find this file and instead run java on it, i.e. `java HelloWorld.class`

Oracle has put up a good example of how to get started [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) which you may want to check out.

Comment: yes i was now it solved & that programs work perfectly:) thank you all

i run like this Java StudentManagement